# in node js insert values are updated undefined value why it happend only last id updated correctly,my db is sqlite3

Tags: node.js

[update query code input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bZUk.png)
when i start server send post request it shows movies upadate succcessfully, but in get request it shows all values updated with undefined value except lastid.
output like shown on[updated post request when call through get it shows updated values like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hGSY.png) image

```
``Content-Type: application/json
{

    "directorId":27,
    "movieName":"Ek villan",
    "leadActor":"Gorilla"
}`
```

this is my post request values
so please help me to solve it

Comment: [why should you not upload image of code or Error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)